How to efficiently find duplicates in a large list of integers in Python?
I have a large list of integers (millions of elements), and I need to find and remove duplicate values from it efficiently. I’ve tried using a simple approach with a for loop, but it’s too slow for very large datasets. Here's what I’ve tried.

I believe your question is slightly incomplete. It would be good to know the end goal of removing duplicates and whether the order of elements is essential for that end goal.
If the order of elements isn't necessary, then using set or converting the list into a set may be the easiest way.
maybe something like data_set = set(data_list)
I understand that in cases where data transformation yields a result resembling a different data type, it may be faster to use the standard library to transform the underlying data type.
But again, converting list to set and then set back to list may not be performant.
